# Word VBA: Hyperlink .Range.Font.TextColor.RGB and compatibility mode

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, fonts, hyperlink

Could someone please let me know why the first line of code below throws error 445 (Object doesn't support this action) when run on a Word document saved in compatibility mode? The second line works just fine.

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(1, 2, 3)

ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Font.Color = RGB(1, 2, 3)
```

As a follow-on to this question, how does the second line even work? Per the VBA reference, the Font object doesn't even have a 'Color' property, just the 'ColorIndex', 'ColorIndexBi' and 'TextColor' ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This complexity is all the fault of patchy Microsoft documentation by the
Office team.

**how does the second line even work**

[Font.Color property (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.color)
is a real property of `Font`, even if it is only documented for Excel.
But as you have found out, it also works for Word.

**why the first line of code below throws error 445**

You are asking why `TextColor.RGB` is an error in compatibility mode.

"Compatibility mode" means working in the mode supported by
older versions of Office.

[Font.TextColor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.font.textcolor)
is a
[ColorFormat object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.colorformat).
The key word here is **object**.

An object should be read-only, because it's an object and not a property.
Strictly speaking, you shouldn't be able to change and set an
object-reference to something else
(you wouldn't need to do that normally),
but you can still modify its state, meaning its properties.

Apparently an older version of VBA had some confusion with the distinction
between object and property, so the reference to `TextColor` translated
internally to what is today known as `TextColor.RGB`.

In newer versions, the distinction between object and property was improved,
so the `.RGB` property could be used instead for more precision.

Microsoft documentation cannot be counted upon to be exact, as it seems
to be a mixture of old and new text. Especially Office documentation.
Many times, "try and see" is required to find out what works and when.

Comment: When the document is not in compatibility mode, I can set TextColor.RGB just fine - [ColorFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.colorformat) objects do have an RGB property.

Comment: Right. I rewrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the [full list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.font) of `Word.Range` methods and properties we can see that `Range` has the [`Font` property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.font).

From the documentation, this `Font` property

> Returns or sets a Font object that represents the character formatting of the specified object. Read/write Font.

Comment: This is correct. But per the VBA reference (and the Intellisense menu) the `Font` object isn't supposed to have a `Color` property, which is what has me confused. It does have a `TextColor` property, which works fine - except with documents in compatibility mode. Yet using .Font.Color works fine in both cases.